# unix - how to remove a byte from a recursive position in a ebcdic file

Tags: unix, ebcdic

I have an ebcdic file and need to remove a byte that recurs every n bytes:

For example:
00 00 00 25 00 0C **25** 00 00 00 00 00 0C **25** 00 78 25 69 67 4C **25** 00 78 90 69 67 4C **25**

I need to remove "25" from position 7, 14, 21, 28, the output would be:

00 00 00 25 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00 78 25 69 67 4C 00 78 90 69 67 4C

I tried to use **cut**:

```
l=`stat -c%s myfile`

for (( i = 1 ; i <= $l ; i += 7 )) ; 
do

 m=`expr $i + 5`  
 cat myfile | cut -c$i-$m` >> fileout

done
```

But the output is not what I expect:

00 00 00 25 00 0C **0A** 00 00 00 00 00 0C **0A** 00 78 25 69 67 4C **0A** 00 78 90 69 67 4C **0A**

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I suggest to implement this in C or in a scripting language that can handle binary data. The shell and most tools are designed to process text input.

Comment: This data looks like *packed decimal* data, i.e. `PIC 9(11) COMP-3` in COBOL, separated by an EBCDIC *line feed* (LF, x'25'). What is the goal of changing the EBCDIC line feed to an ASCII line feed?

Comment: @phunsoft I am not tryng to substitute the EBCDIC line feed, I am trying to remove it.

Comment: Actually I managed to do it, using dd. Couldn't get good performance, though.